# Lucene search with complex query

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Here's what I want to do, using pseudo-code:

```
lucene.Find((someField == "bar" || someField == "baz") && anotherField == "foo");
```

Or in English, "find all documents where *someField* is 'bar' or 'baz', and where *anotherField* is 'foo'".

How can I do a query like this with Lucene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lucene query syntax:

```
+(someField:bar someField:baz) +anotherField:foo
```

The "+" means that the term is required, just like Google search syntax. The parentheses group terms to act like a single term. Without a "+" (or "-"), a term is optional; at least one of the terms has to match, and the more terms that match, the higher the score.

Pass this string to the `QueryParser` to create a `Query` object. The query can then be passed to one of several search methods, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. In the meantime, I'll mark this as the correct answer. I'll let you know if it works as expected.